# How to read a javascript object

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I am using from Microsoft the
Live Connect Developer Center

It returns this type of variable for a contact but I don't know of a simple way to read it, would perform split on it but do not know how to read this object:

```
{"id":"contact.0d3d6bf0000000000000000000000000", "first_name":"William", "last_name":"Shakespeare", "name":"William Shakespeare", "gender":null, "is_friend":false, "is_favorite":false, "user_id":"2ae098749083cb3d", "email_hashes":["a790b818acfdef744a23bef534dfd9a4a53aa834250bdfe55f6874543129daa6"], "updated_time":"2012-10-04T19:23:34+0000"}
```

I'd need to access name and email_hashes with what's inside of it:
a790b818acfdef744a23bef534dfd9a4a53aa834250bdfe55f6874543129daa6 - without the brackets.

Just don't know how to read this kind of object.

Comment: What's your environment?

Comment: That is "an array". You'll want to access the first element (index = 0): `x = {a: ["b"]}; alert(x.a[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like JSON. If you're using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON('{"id":"contact..."}');
alert('name: ' + jsonData.id);
```

See the docs for more usage examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse()` is specifically designed to take a string in JSON format and produce a JavaScript object, from which you can then access properties.

Comment: Probably out of scope of this question, but please mind that JSON object is not available on all browsers by default.

Answer (score 0):

The response you're receiving is a key/value pair. You can access any value with the key

```
obj[key] // value
```

or

```
obj.key // value
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
var x = {"id":"contact.0d3d6bf0000000000000000000000000", "first_name":"William", "last_name":"Shakespeare", "name":"William Shakespeare", "gender":null, "is_friend":false, "is_favorite":false, "user_id":"2ae098749083cb3d", "email_hashes":["a790b818acfdef744a23bef534dfd9a4a53aa834250bdfe55f6874543129daa6"], "updated_time":"2012-10-04T19:23:34+0000"}
```

then

```
x.email_hashes
```

returns

```
["a790b818acfdef744a23bef534dfd9a4a53aa834250bdfe55f6874543129daa6"]
```

and

```
x.email_hashes[0]
```

returns

```
"a790b818acfdef744a23bef534dfd9a4a53aa834250bdfe55f6874543129daa6"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get your variable with the JSON, do this:

```
var stringData = {}, // Incoming data
    data = JSON.parse(stringData);
```

Then, you can access the variables like this:

```
var id = data.id,
    firstName = data.first_name;
```

To access array values, do this:

```
var emailHashes = data.email_hashes;
if (emailHashes.length > 0) {
    var i = 0;

    for (; i < emailHashes.length; i++) {
         // perform some action on them.
    }         
}
```